# Erroneous deletion of comment on SO, or did the system lose it?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, comments

A comment of mine was either deleted or lost on an SO thread. Indicators and current context  indicate it was once there.

Go to the following SO question, and my (jdk's) visible comment:
[Display Computer Info on an ASP.NET Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011090/display-computer-info-on-an-asp-net-page/3011105#3011105)

Can somebody with high rep look into this and see what happened, or is it just gone forever?

It's a curious anomaly because I can think of no reason the comment should have been flagged.

Comment: Are you 10000% sure you didn't accidentally delete it yourself by clicking on the `x`? Just checking to make sure.

Comment: Could it have been seen as offensive? If enough people flag it, it would be automatically deleted, or a moderator could step in.

Comment: @sth: It was a comment about .NET having all the needed stuff and Java not being needed (on a .NET thread), potentially controversial to zealots but not offensive by any means.

Comment: @Down..: I wondered about that myself. I've never done it before, and if I did by accident it won't be known until somebody looks into it. I mean to say if I had clicked the X by accident and know I did it, I wouldn't have bothered posting to meta - I would have just retyped it.

Comment: How can you be a .NET developer with the initials @jdk???  ;)

Comment: @Bill: It's the great irony because those are my true three initials. How delighted I was back around ~1995!

Comment: If someone could check deleted comments, please take a look on comment id 3077491 and 3077475, those 2 is missing from the range between John commented and replied to jdk.

Comment: @S.Mark: No one can see deleted comments, except the devs by going into the database directly. Given the comments above, most likely the comments in question were flagged to the point of deletion, or removed by a moderator.

Comment: My conscience is clear knowing I didn't say anything bad or offensive to have comments deleted by, and this is community run so we will get some rapacious people and strong biases. It makes we wonder how many comments are removed because of those things rather than through objective moderation. Regardless it's only a comment in the grand scheme and I'm curious more than anything, so if no devs ever happen to shed light on this (indeed there are likely less trivial things they could be doing) well then I'll be on my way.

Comment: You know what, call me suspicious, but I'm also wondering if we have a rogue moderator out there that favours Java highly enough  to remove anything that might shed it in a negative light. I will likely never know the answer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was flagged as offensive, and I thought it had the wrong tone, so I opted to remove it.

We look at HUNDREDS of flagged comments a day, and decisions are made quickly.

Comment: Thanks. The eternal challenge of deciphering mood and tone over a staid medium, in a split second, also of poster to provide it properly. Feel free to post the comment here as an example for posterity so people reading this thread can know what was flagged and decide for themselves if I had business to post to meta.